# website IP changed for a while

Tags: web-hosting

After multiple research for a solution, I couldn't find a way to resolve my problem other than ask for your help.
So, recently i had changed my web hosting from lws to websitewelcome, and from time time i cannot access the website, when i ping on my website, i got an answer of hr  IP adress http://91.234.195.224 which is different of the normal IP adress of my website.So, when i look for the owner of this IP adress i find that it belongs to my old hoster.
In the same time when I got this problem, I try to access my website from another terminal (my smartphone) and the website access with no problem.
I cannot find a logical explanation of what happen but this is the situation.
Have any one seen this issue before? Any propositions?

Comment: If you tell us the domain name, we can research it. It's probably a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the dns records are being cached somewhere a little bit longer than they should have. Essentially, the DNS system works by asking a server if it has the record for a domain. If it doesn't have the record, it will query a server that most likely does, and if that one doesn't have it, it'll query the next and so on. If a server does have the record, it will store it in its cache so it doesn't have to search for it next time. The cached records expire after a certain time so it sounds like they just haven't timed out yet.

How long ago did you change hosting providers?